# Create a python standalone executable for CentOS

Tags: python, centos, python-2.6, python-standalone

I have a python script written to run on a system in our office which runs CentOS. It has Python2.6.6 installed by root user and hence I don't have access to install pip or any other tool. My goal is to create a standalone executable such that users shall be able to run the python script without the hassle of writing commands and running it from the terminal. Here's the script

```
import Tkinter as tk

global root


def file_download():
    root.withdraw()
    # download functionality code
    root.deiconify()


def file_upload():
    root.withdraw()
    # upload functionality code
    root.deiconify()


def sim_dialog():
    global root

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Sample file manager')
    root.resizable(0, 0)
    dwnld = tk.Button(root, text="Download", width=10, command=file_download)
    dwnld.pack(expand=0, padx=90, pady=10)
    upld = tk.Button(root, text="Upload", width=10, command=file_upload)
    upld.pack(expand=0, padx=90, pady=10)

    root.mainloop()


sim_dialog()
```

Just like windows, double click should launch the application. After checking some forums added shebang line #!/usr/bin/env python2.6 in my script but nothing happens.

Please help me figure out (one of the below)

- Correct shebang line
- Create standalone executable for CentOS. Please note I don't have root access and hence I can't install pip or any other tools or libraries.
- Create standalone executable for CentOS using Python on Windows. I'm free to do anything on windows as I have successfully created virtual environment.

Thanks in advance for the help and please let me know if any more information is required.

---

I've been suggested to create desktop shortcut

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false          # true if it's a terminal application
Exec=/home/user001/Desktop/sim_dialog.py  # or just the name, e.g. polo-gtk
Name=sim_dialog
Comment=
Icon=
```

Ran this desktop shortcut with and without shebang line. Doesn't work in both the cases.

Comment: you can create a bash executable which runs the python script, or you can make a desktop shortcut, this way answer your question:[https://teonotebook.wordpress.com/2019/03/14/create-a-desktop-shortcut-in-centos-7/](https://teonotebook.wordpress.com/2019/03/14/create-a-desktop-shortcut-in-centos-7/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Still no luck @t0mas